# I get the following Html, using only Html Dom, how can I get the closet li of ul

Tags: html

I get the following Html, using only Html Dom, how can I get the closet li of ul (class=2)? (Excluding all the li under class = 3):

```
<ul class="2">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
  <ul class="3">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
  <ul class="3">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
  <ul class="3">
    <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
      <ul class="4">
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
     <ul class="4">
       <li>text</li>
       <li>text</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at least chrome (I only tried google-chrome) does not like the class named number `2` so I renamed them to `two` and so on.
So Given the Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="two">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
    <ul class="three">
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
    <ul class="three">
      <li>text</li>
      <li>text</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
    <ul class="three">
      <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
        <ul class="four">
          <li>text</li>
          <li>text</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="haschild"><a>text</a>
       <ul class="four">
         <li>text</li>
         <li>text</li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And using the selector : `document.querySelector('ul.two > li:nth-child(1)')`
I get this : `<li>text</li>`

[image: Css Selector]

---

Update : If the class has to be a number (out of our control)
Then at least for me the implicit selector does not work
SO we fall back to imperative style (lots of mistakes possible here :) )

So now the `class="2"` is possible to be selected. Warning: Some Pages that Update the Html Dynamically can have different(old/ initial) attributes despite the dom being changed. I am not sure here -- only experimentation will tell.

```js
for(var elem of ul) {
    if (elem.getAttribute('class') == '2') {
        var all_lis = elem.querySelectorAll('li');
        for(var li_elem of all_lis) {
            var next_first_ul = li_elem.querySelector('ul');
            if(next_first_ul !== null) {
                break;
            }
            console.log(li_elem);
            
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

[image]
Here you should get the `li`'s until the `li` with a `ul` if you also need to include that li then move the console.log before the if

Comment: In my case, it is 2. Well, Im doing crawler, doest it affect at all?

Comment: And Can I get all the li? Not only one?

Comment: Hmm Not sure, if you are writing a web crawler then the engine / software that is doing the parsing may have a different set / implementation of the selectors YMMV then.
Getting all the the `li` until the next `ul` I am looking into.

Comment: @ĐinhVạnHoàngAn See the updated answer, this now is more involved to accomodate the class named `2` and so on, 
`console.log` is where you need to collect the elements for further use. Hope this helps!

Comment: `document.querySelector('ul[class=2] > li:nth-child(1)')` could be worth a shot. Of course if the element has multiple classes this won't work.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer ^^ it worked ^^

Comment: If this is answered could you accept the answer? Thanks! 
Also @JonP Thanks for the selector I forgot about this one!  :)